# Making Vue.js provide/inject reactive

Tags: vue.js

I am getting my head round the different ways of communicating between components and their children, grandchildren, etc., and have been taking a look at provide/inject for the first time. I can get this to work fine without being reactive (which I know is the way it is designed), but cannot get reactive behaviour using an observed object. Let's say I have a nested object structure, A > B > C, where A is the grandparent of C. I have a data property of A, 'page', changes to which I would like to observe in grandchild C. If I just provide 'page' in A and inject 'page' in C, it's not reactive (by design). I thought if I did something like this instead it might work:

In provider:

```
data() {
    return {
      page: null,
      obj:{currentPage:this.page}
    }
},


provide(){
     return {
       obj: this.obj
     }
  }
```

In child or grandchild:

```
inject: ['obj']
```

But it doesn't. If I try to use obj.currentPage in the grandchild component, it is undefined.

I'm sure this is pretty straightforward. What am I not getting?

Comment: If you want the grandchild to observe changes in the grandparent, there are probably several ways to do it: (1) use an event bus, (2) pass down the parent data as prop all the way down to the grandchild, so the grandchild can observed the inherited data itself, or (3) use VueX (probably an overkill tho)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware of those solutions. I am trying to find out about provide/inject here, though, so I know how to use it properly.

Comment: just my guess, maybe because you use the same name "obj" for both data and provider, try changing one

Comment: No, the name makes no difference.

Answer (score 28):

I spent a lot of time, trying to make provided/injected object reactive, and after all it was eureka! We can simply pass a function returning an object, not an object themself.

It seems as a good solution to me.

Provider:

```js
data(){
 return {
   something: ...,
 }
}

provide(){
 return {
  getSomething: () => this.something,
 }
}
```

Descedant component:

```js
inject: ['getSomething'],

computed: {
 something(){
  return this.getSomething();
 }
}
```

So, in descedant component, computed property `this.something` became reactive.

Comment: did not work for  me in vue 3

Comment: Are you using TypeScript?

Comment: No I don't use it

Comment: This also did not work for me in Vue 3. The difference in how props and injects work is pretty annoying.

Comment: This did work for me in Vue3 interesting enough. I couldn't get it to work the docs were saying. I'm using this with Apollo and the method way (above) worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Well, as ever the answer turned out to be in a completely different place from where I was looking. There is nothing wrong with the reactivity of the 'obj' object being provided. The problem lies in the fact that the object is not being updated in the parent data object. I had `obj:{currentPage:this.page}` assuming that when `this.page` changes, the property within `obj` would be updated, but it isn't. So I have two options here, unless I've missed something: firstly, use a `watch` on `page`, updating the `obj` property; or forget about `this.page` altogether and make sure any updates which were hitherto done to `this.page` are instead done to `this.obj.currentPage`. It's just a case of deciding which approach is the less messy. All part of an interesting learning exercise.

Comment: Thanks for your self answer, solving my confusion.